# cannot send data by using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i need in sert data by ajax , i have two pages, once is form that have icon that i click on it and send me to other page and insert new data

here the ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#dialog1").click(function() {
        $('#welcome').slideToggle('#loginhandle'); 
        $('#loginhandle').show("slow");

      var name = $("input#ausers_ID").val();
      var dataString = 'ausers_ID='+ ausers_ID  ;
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "OpenCashier.php",
               data: dataString,
               success: function(msg) {
                 $('#loginhandle').slideToggle('#msgreturn');
                 $('#msgreturn').show("slow");
                 $('#msgreturn').html(msg)
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(1500, function() {
        });
      }
     });
    return false;
    });


});
</script>
```

when i click this bottom

```
<input type="submit" id="dialog1" name="dialog1" value="Insert" />
```

we must call this page

```
<? session_start();
include("sec.php");
include("../include/connect.php");
include("../include/safe.php");

    if($_POST["dialog1"]){

            // Every thing is OK    
            $ausers_ID=$_POST["ausers_ID"];
            $cashiers_CashierOpenDate=date('Y/m/d');
            $query="INSERT INTO `cashiers` ( `cashiers_CashierID` , `cashiers_CashierOpenDate` , `cashiers_User` , `cashiers_Status` , `cashiers_Delete`  ) VALUES ('', '$cashiers_CashierOpenDate', '$ausers_ID', '0','0');";
            mysql_query($query);
            $num=mysql_affected_rows();         
            if($num==1)
                $message="Account was added successfully";
            else                
                $message=$_POST["dialog1"]." Account is already exists in database";
    }
?>
```

but data cannot insert why !!!

Comment: You are not doing any error checking in your PHP script, so you will not be getting any error messages if your SQL query fails.

Comment: Have you tried the PHP script directly? Such as create a simple POST form or use cURL from the command line. `curl -F "var1=val1" -F "var2=val2" http://wwww.example.com/myscript.php`Doing this should return any fatal PHP errors if you have display_errors turned on in php.ini. As suggested above you need to also add in error handling for SQL, calling `mysql_error();`.

Comment: Incidentally, you're not sanitizing `$ausers_ID` before composing the query string. Very risky. Have you learned to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to include the "dialog1" parameter used in your PHP code.

I would suggest to change your data to sent to :

```
var dataString = {ausers_ID : ausers_ID, dialog1 : true}
```

Comment: Thank you i miss the dialog1 parameter

Comment: var dataString = 'ausers_ID='+ ausers_ID+'&dialog1='+true  ;

Comment: Don't forget to close the subject by clicking on the green tick

Comment: How to close  he subject by clicking on the green tick ?

Comment: There is a litle tick in grey near the right answer (on the left). Just click on it to close the subject